# How to make logstash file input work on windows machine?

Tags: logstash, logstash-file

I have a runningversion of logstash on my windows machine.
The file input filter does not work. The logstash script starts and nothing happens -> no success or error.
Generate input filter, and stdin all work properly.
The file input filter stopped working after 2-3 days.

The file output filter works fine.

PFB my settings.

```
 file {
    path => "D:\softwares\logstash\data\sample4.txt"
    # path => "D:/softwares/logstash/data/sample4.txt"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"
    ignore_older => 0  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ignore_older => 0
```

In filebeat, setting ignore_older to zero turns off age based filtering. For a logstash file input it ignores any files more than zero seconds old, which can result in it ignoring all files. Delete this option.

Also, ever since the conversion of logstash core from ruby to java, a backslash in the path option is treated as an escape, so `path => "D:\softwares\logstash\data\sample4.txt"` is treated as if it were `path => "D:softwareslogstashdatasample4.txt"`. Use forward slash instead.